# Rails adding id as a param in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, param

I'm sure that this has something to do with my N00b syntax but I'm having trouble working out what it is...

I am creating a menu by looping through items in my subpages table and creating a link for each item that is returned, Like this:

```
<% @subpages.each do |menu| %>
<%= link_to(menu.name, {:controller => 'public', :action => "page", :id => menu.permalink }, :class => "show action footer-link") %>
<% end %>
```

this is working fine on the homepage of my site but if you visit one of the subpages, let's say the about us page:

```
http://localhost:3000/public/page/about-us
```

and then try to use the menu again to visit "contact us", instead of taking you to this link as i would expect:

```
http://localhost:3000/public/page/contact-us
```

It takes you to this link:

```
http://localhost:3000/public/page/about-us?id=contact-us
```

What school-boy error am I making here?

Thanks in advance.

edit: my routes

```
  root :to => "public#index"
  get 'admin', :to => 'access#menu'  
  get 'public/show/:permalink', :to => 'public#show'
  get 'public/page/:permalink', :to => 'public#page'
```

Comment: Please paste your routes here.

Comment: added the routes to the OQ - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work  by passing the :permalink param to the controller instead of the ID

```
<% @subpages.each do |menu| %>
    <%= link_to(menu.name, { :action => "page", :permalink => menu.permalink }, :class => "show action footer-link") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
<% @subpages.each do |menu| %>
  <%= link_to(menu.name, page_public_path(menu.permalink), :class => "show action footer-link") %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Comment: hmm.. that is giving me an error.. NoMethodError in Public#page
Showing /Users/Simo/Sites/nvs-git/app/views/layouts/public.html.erb where line #68 raised:

undefined method `page_public_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f81caf2dfe8>:0x007f81ca10c9a0>